# gremlin-python - unable to add edge property

Tags: python, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

I'm having great trouble adding properties to an edge using the `gremlin_python` wrapper.

I'm able to create the edge, as so:

```
eid1='123'
eid2='456'
edge = g.V().has('eid', eid1).addE('transaction').to(g.V().has('entity_id',eid2)).next()
```

But, adding properties to the edge doesn't work. As in: the code runs without error, but no changes occur on the edge itself, so when after I call `g.E(edge).valueMap.toList()`, it returns an empty list.

```
g.E(edge).property('foo','bar').iterate()    <-- I've also tried this without iterate.
```

It also doesn't work if I create the node and add a property on the same line of code.

The same code - but executed in the gremlin console - runs as expected. i.e., after creating the edge and assigning the property:

```
gremlin> g.E(edge).valueMap().toList()
==>{foo=bar}
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update**

I was unable to get this to work using the python wrapper on the graph traversal object, instead I ran the code through the client, which works as expected. But this is a workaround, and not a solution.

```
gremlin_client = client.Client('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', 'g')

query = "g.V().has('eid', '123').addE('transaction').to(g.V().has('eid','456')).property('foo','bar').next()"
gremlin_client.submit(query).all().result()
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "doesn't execute"? do you get an error? or it just executes and no change to the database occurs?

Comment: Hi Stephen, the latter, the code runs without error, but no change to the database occurs

Comment: Maybe the edits makes this more clear, thanks

Comment: hmm - could you try `g.E(edge.id()).property(...)`?

Comment: No luck unfortunately. Using `...edge.id...` works in the console, but fails in the same way as described via gremlin_python.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your scenario on 3.4.3-SNAPSHOT and don't see a problem:

```
>>> g.addV().property('entity_id','123').iterate()
[['addV'], ['property', 'entity_id', '123'], ['none']]
>>> g.addV().property('entity_id','456').iterate()
[['addV'], ['property', 'entity_id', '456'], ['none']]
>>> e = g.V().has('entity_id','123').addE('transaction').to(__.V().has('entity_id','456')).next()
>>> g.E(e).property('foo','bar').iterate()
[['E', e[4][0-transaction->2]], ['property', 'foo', 'bar'], ['none']]
>>> g.E(e).valueMap().toList()
[{u'foo': u'bar'}]
```

I do note that your example code does have a syntax error - looking at:

```
eid1='123'
eid2='456'
edge = g.V().has('eid', eid1).addE('transaction').to(g.V().has('entity_id',eid2)).next()
```

Specifically, you mix "eid" and "entity_id" as your vertex identifiers. Assuming "eid" is wrong and it should be "entity_id" I could see how this traversal would fail without update (as the initial vertex is never found) and then leave you in a position where you couldn't update the edge because it was never created.

In response to comments below I also tried this with including a `property()` update with TinkerGraph and did not experience problems:

```
>>> g.addV().property('entity_id','123').iterate()
[['addV'], ['property', 'entity_id', '123'], ['none']]
>>> g.V().toList()
[v[0]]
>>> g.addV().property('entity_id','456').iterate()
[['addV'], ['property', 'entity_id', '456'], ['none']]
>>> g.V().has('entity_id','123').addE('transaction').to(__.V().has('entity_id','456')).property('weight',0.1).property('time',1000000).iterate()
[['V'], ['has', 'entity_id', '123'], ['addE', 'transaction'], ['to', [['V'], ['has', 'entity_id', '456']]], ['property', 'weight', 0.1], ['property', 'time', 1000000], ['none']]
>>> g.E().valueMap().toList()
[{'time': 1000000, 'weight': 0.1}]
```

I'm really not sure what could be wrong.

Comment: I have the same problem. And I can confirm that adding the edge and then set the property works fine. But do you know why I cannot add the property when I add the edge? Like `g.V(V1).addE('label').to(V2).property('START',1566660000).property('STOP', 999999999999999999).next()`

Comment: i'm not sure what could be wrong. these are such basic operations. what graph database are you using?

Comment: I'm using TinkerGraph memory db. But i suspect that the problem is with python lib. Because using gremlin console is working fine. I will test ot with AWS neptune that is my target db.

Comment: I tried with TinkerGraph and I'm not seeing any problem using `property()` however i do notice that you get a nasty error with the property value of "999999999999999999" - definitely not subtle. that number is outside the bounds of an Java 32 bit int. The error appear in the server logs more plainly than on the client which isn't so good. you need to type it to "long" like `statics.long(999999999999999999)` and then it works fine. Not sure if that's your issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

I fell into the same situation. Using `edgeid.id['@value']['relationId']` worked for me.

```
g.E(edgeid.id['@value']['relationId']).property('foo','bar').iterate()
```

When we simply use `g.E()` in gremlin python it works but using edge to filter the edges is not supported in a way we expect. `g.E(edge).toList()` was empty. I figured it was not able to search the edges. So I used `relationId` directly and it worked.